# Firefox extension that will allow Chrome-like tab closing for Firefox 3?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, browser-tabs, firefox-3.6

[This is the behavior I'm talking about.](http://frankyan.wordpress.com/2010/07/30/making-tab-closing-easy/) It's coming to Firefox 4, but is there an extension that will give this functionality to 3.6?

Comment: I've got FF4 and it's not there :(

Comment: @fredley I just got Firefox 5.0 and it is there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can have the exact same behavior in FF 3.

But if you want the close button to always be at the same spot, you can use the add-on [Close Button](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1950/):

> Adds a Close Tab (or Window, or
>   Browser) button to the toolbar, so you
>   can put it where you want it.

[image]

Another useful add-on is [Multiple Tab Handler](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4838/) to close multiple tabs with one click.

Answer (score 2):

Also, you can **middle click** anywhere in a tab to close it. That works in just about *everything* thing with tabs. (FF, Chrome, notepad ++) I find this just as easy, no need to hit just a small "x", click the tab.

If you are on a laptop **clicking both mouse buttons will do the same.**